# Fonts too bold under OS X 10.8

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting crisper fonts in OS X after switching from Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/457153/getting-crisper-fonts-in-os-x-after-switching-from-windows)

I am using chrome browser, and i am a guy who never used mac before, i switched from ubuntu to os x. Now  the fonts look too bold for me comparatively to windows 7/ ubuntu 12.04. For comparison sake, here is the image, the above shows the fonts under os x using chrome browser and beneath those shows the ones in windows 7. 
[image]

Are these normal or is there any issues with my setup? I am using mac mini; which i upgraded from Lion to Mountain lion. I connect it with Samsung 23 inches 1080p LED monitor. Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This seems to be off-topic as this has nothing to do with programming or development as stated in the FAQ.

Comment: Ok can you please  close the topic then?

Comment: In general to "answer" your question: this is and was always the same with Mac OS and other OS like Windows and Linux derivates and it is just based on your font settings. Apparently Apple implemented the settings so that the fonts appear much clearer and distinctive. Furthermore, I flagged your question but I do not have the rights to close this question. Only time will do so when more people flag this question, too.

Comment: Text does normally look bolder on OS X, but there's a hidden preference for using a lighter text rendering style. See the question above.